# My carousel images do not display in IE9 or FF

Tags: carousel

I am a simple web designer and technical writer who was tasked with creating carousels for four pages on my client's Jive-powered website.

I used some code that they already had on this page: https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/bsm_initiatives.

I have edited and placed that code on a Jive overview page. The images display and rotate perfectly in Chrome, but not in IE9, where I get the dreaded red X or in FF12, where you can only see the dots).

One page is here: https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/tap
The code on all of the pages is the same other than the images.

I have tested it two ways, with relative and absolute links, and that does not seem to make a difference (not that I thought it would, but we recently changed the site from http to https, so I thought it was worth a shot).

The code is below. Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="bmc_banner">
    <ul class="bjqs">
      <li><a href="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/tap/product_directory?view=documents"><img src="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/servlet/JiveServlet/download/21201-6-31470099/Find-an-Integration.jpg" width="940" height="300" border="0"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/docs/DOC-19908"><img src="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/servlet/JiveServlet/download/21201-5-31470094/Market-Solutions.jpg" width="940" height="300" border="0"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/community/tap/technology_alliances_directory"><img src="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/servlet/JiveServlet/download/21201-5-31470091/TAP-Partners.jpg" width="940" height="300" border="0"/></a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.bmc.com/education"><img src="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/servlet/JiveServlet/download/21201-5-31470096/BMC-Education.jpg" width="940" height="300" border="0"/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>      
</div>

<script src="https://communities.bmc.com/communities/themes/generated_advanced_skin_global/template/widget/7summits/scripts/basic-jquery-slider.min.js"></script>    
<script>
  $j(document).ready(function() {

    $j('#bmc_banner').bjqs({
      'animation' : 'fade',
      'width' : 940,
      'height' : 300,
      'showControls' : false,
      'animationDuration' : 1000,
      'rotationSpeed' : 6000
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't access the images directly, the application is wanting you to be logged in. So presumably you are logged in on Chrome but not IE or FF.  Try accessing loginhttps://communities.bmc.com/communities/servlet/JiveServlet/download/21201-5-31470094/Market-Solutions.jpg directly, you will see what I mean.  Put the image in a different directory I would say.

Comment: Oh lord. I feel so stupid. Thanks!

Comment: Don't feel stupid, anyone can make a mistake like that ! :) Glad it got sorted.